# How to render DIV content on Html5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i got a code which may render div content on canvas but many area i just do not understand. so guide me. here is the code which i got it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = "data:image/svg+xml," +
           "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' style='font-size:12px'>" +
                "<ul> <li style='color:red'> hello </li>  <li style='color:green'>thomas</li> </ul> "  +   
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";

var img = new Image();
img.src = data;
img.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); }
```

1) what is the meaning of `data:image/svg+xml`
2) what is the meaning of `<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>`

3) what is `<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>`

if possible please explain their meaning & usage.

another most important issue that **Canvas & browser compatibility issue
we know that many browser version do not support html5 Canvas and in that case we can fallback and load flash canvas**

so guide me how to load flash canvas and also the most important is to draw or render div content on flash canvas.

looking for guidance in detail. thanks

Comment: *"we know that many browser version do not support html5 Canvas"* this is not correct - actually MOST browsers supports canvas today. http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: browser with old version do not support. in that case i want to load flash canvas and want to draw div content on that flash canvas....have any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it is not the root element, the svg element can be used to nest a standalone SVG fragment inside the current document (which can be an HTML document). This standalone fragment has its own viewPort and its own coordinate system.

The foreignObject element allows for inclusion of a foreign XML namespace which has its graphical content drawn by a different user agent. The included foreign graphical content is subject to SVG transformations and compositing.

you can find source from this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

Comment: thanks but what about Canvas & browser compatibility issue we know that many browser version do not support html5 Canvas and in that case we can fallback and load flash canvas

Comment: There is no other way to use canvas in old browsers. at present u r on right track to use flashcanvas. or https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills this is the same thing like flash canvas.

Comment: You need a warning with your answer: Using foreignObject to capture other-domain resources is increasingly disallowed by current security rules.  Mozilla may still allow it, but most browsers do not allow.